# Read from csv file into 2d array and sort the array using c

Tags: c, arrays, csv

In my csv file, currently i have data like

```
45454, 32, 78, C, 67
45452, 22, 38, C, 34
```

I want to add the data into 2d array and sort them.
Currently i am using this approach

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<String.h>

void getData(char *buff);
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    int count = -1;
    do
    {
        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp);
        count++;
        if(count != 1)
        {
            printf(buff);
            getData(buff);
        }
    }
    while((getc(fp))!= EOF);


}
void getData(char buff[])
{
    char *token = strtok(buff,",");
    int counter=0;

    while( token != NULL )
    {
        counter++;
        printf(" %s\n",token);
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
    }
}
```

But i want to read data using fgets and sscanf and store them into single dimensional VLA’s (variable-length arrays)
How can i do that?

Comment: How do you want to sort them?

Comment: `while((getc(fp))!= EOF);` is wrong.

Comment: First column name is ID, i want to sort by ID.

Comment: What do you know about the structure of the CSV data?  Do you have a header line to worry about?  How are you planning to keep all the fields — in a structure?  You'll need to allocate memory to hold the parsed CSV data.  When you've done that, you'll need to sort it, but the appropriate sorting process depends on how you organize the data.

Comment: Where is the 2D array? And if you want a 1D array, why do you ask about a 2D array?

Comment: Currently i have no 2D array, don't know how to do this.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id, exam1, exam2, exam3;
    char grade;
} Row;

int getSize(char* filename)
{
    int rows=0;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, file) != NULL)
    {
        rows++;
    }

    return rows;
}

void sort(Row *a, int length)
{
    int j;
    Row temp;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j].id < a[j - 1].id || (a[j].id == a[j - 1].id && a[j].grade < a[j - 1].grade))
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

int binarySearch(Row *row, int size, int key)
{
    int i, start, end, mid;
    start = 0;
    end = size;

    do
    {
        mid = (int)((start + end)/2);
        if(row[mid].id == key)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("+--------+");
            printf("-----------+");
            printf("-------+\n");
            printf("| Index  |  Student  | Grade |\n");
            printf("+--------+");
            printf("-----------+");
            printf("-------+\n");
            printf("| %-5d  |  %-5d   |\t %-4c|\n", mid+1, row[mid].id, row[mid].grade);
            printf("+--------+");
            printf("-----------+");
            printf("-------+\n");
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
        else if(row[mid].id > key)
        {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    while(start <= end);

    if(start > end)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("+--------+");
        printf("-----------+");
        printf("-------+\n");
        printf("| Index  |  Student  | Grade |\n");
        printf("+--------+");
        printf("-----------+");
        printf("-------+\n");
        printf("| N/A   |  N/A    |\t N/A|\n");
        printf("+--------+");
        printf("-----------+");
        printf("-------+\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* filename = "grades.csv";
    int rows = getSize(filename);
    printf("There are %d lines in file grades.csv.\n\n", rows);
    FILE* stream = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    Row *row = malloc(sizeof(*row) * rows);
    char line[1024];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Original:\n");
    printf("+--------+");
    printf("-----------+");
    printf("-------+");
    printf("------+");
    printf("-------+\n");
    printf("| Student|    Exam 1 | Exam 2|Exam 3| Grade |\n");
    while(fgets(line, 1024, stream) != NULL)
    {
        printf("+--------+");
        printf("-----------+");
        printf("-------+");
        printf("------+");
        printf("-------+\n");
        sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%c", &row[i].id, &row[i].exam1, &row[i].exam2, &row[i].exam3, &row[i].grade);
        printf("| %d |\t %-4d|\t %-4d|\t%-4d|\t%-4c|\n", row[i].id, row[i].exam1, row[i].exam2, row[i].exam3, row[i].grade);
        i++;
    }
    printf("+--------+");
    printf("-----------+");
    printf("-------+");
    printf("------+");
    printf("-------+\n");
    printf("\n\n");


    printf("Sorted:\n");
    sort(row, rows);
    printf("+--------+");
    printf("-----------+");
    printf("-------+\n");
    printf("| Index  |  Student  | Grade |\n");
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("+--------+");
        printf("-----------+");
        printf("-------+\n");
        printf("| %-5d  |  %-5d   |\t %-4c|\n", i+1, row[i].id, row[i].grade);
    }
    printf("+--------+");
    printf("-----------+");
    printf("-------+\n");

    int sid;
    int ex = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter student ID (-1 to quit): ");
start:
        scanf("%d", &sid);

        if(sid == -1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(sid > 100000 && sid < 999999)
        {
            binarySearch(row, rows, sid);
            printf("\n\nEnter student ID (-1 to quit): ");
            goto start;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nERROR and enter again ([100000,9999999] and -1 to quit): ");
            goto start;
        }
    }

    fclose(stream);
    free(row);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a 2-d array. You just need an array which holds your lines. Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct row {
    int id;
    int col1;
    int col2;
    char col3;
    int col4;
};

int cmp(const void *a1, const void *a2) {
    const struct row *r1 = a1;
    const struct row *r2 = a2;
    return r1->id - r2->id;
}

void line_to_row(char *buff, struct row *r)
{
    char *saveptr;
    char *token = strtok_r(buff, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    r->id = atoi(token);

    token = strtok_r(buff, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    r->col1 = atoi(token);

    token = strtok_r(buff, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    r->col2 = atoi(token);

    token = strtok_r(buff, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    while (*token != '\0') {
        r->col3 = *token;
        token++;
    }

    r->col4 = atoi(buff + 1);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file1.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    char buff[1024 + 1];
    int c, i = 0, len = 10;
    struct row *rows = malloc(sizeof(*rows) * len);
    struct row *temp = rows;

    while (fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp)) {
        if (i == len - 1) {
            len += 10;
            temp = realloc(rows, sizeof(*rows) * len);
            if (temp == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
            rows = temp;
        }
        line_to_row(buff, &rows[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    len = i;
    temp = realloc(rows, sizeof(*rows) * len);

    if (temp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    rows = temp;

    qsort(rows, len, sizeof(*rows), &cmp);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", rows[i].id);
    }
    free(rows);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In windows, it says undefined reference to strsep, Is there any alternative?

Comment: Use `strtok` in place of `strsep`. Converting shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Actually i have data like 

45454, 32, 78, 67, G

for that it shows 0 in many line

Comment: Making minor changes to the program shouldn't be that tough. I am not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I replaced strsep with strtok_r for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to help :) Accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I wrote the full code with myself.